# Functions to check if the user's input is correct not working

Tags: c++

I have created some C++ code that is supposed to check to see if a user's input is correct but it isn't quite working how I want it to. Whenever you type an integer first, and then a couple of characters after it, the terminal spams would you like to try again y/n a couple of times. I have tried to limit the amount of times it can output this, but nothing has worked.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

using namespace std;

int again()
{

    char yorn = 'q';

    cout << "\n Would you like to run this program again? y/n: ";
    cin >> yorn;

    if (cin.fail()) {

        int dof1 = 1; // dof1 stands for don't overflow 1
        for (int i = 0; i < dof1; i++) {
            cout << "ERROR -- You did not enter a valid symbol";
            // get rid of failure state
            cin.clear();
            // discard 'bad' character(s)
            cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
            bool check = again();
            if (check == true) {
                check = false;
                return again();
            }
            else
                return 0;
        }
    }
    switch (yorn) {

    case 'y':
        return true;
        break;

    case 'n':
        return false;
        break;

    default:
        return again();
        break;
    }
}

int main()
{

    int choice = 0;
    cout << "\nWelcome to the Weight Tracker! Type 000 at any time to exit\n"
         << "Choose the option you would like to use below \n"
         << "1)  \n"
         << "2)  \n"
         << "3)  \n"
         << "Option selected: ";
    cin >> choice;
    if (cin.fail()) {

        int dof2 = 1; // dof2 stands for don't overflow 2
        for (int i = 0; i < dof2; i++) {
            cout << "ERROR -- You did not enter an integer";
            // get rid of failure state
            cin.clear();
            // discard 'bad' character(s)
            cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
            bool check = again();
            if (check == true) {
                check = false;
                return main();
            }
            else
                return 0;
        }
    }
    switch (choice) {

    case 1:
        cout << " use later";
        break;

    case 2:
        cout << " use later";
        break;

    case 3:
        cout << " use later";
        break;

    default:
        cout << "ERROR -- Input invalid \n";
        bool check = again();
        if (check == true) {
            check = false;
            return main();
        }
        else
            return 0;
        break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Call main recursively? Are you sure you want to do it this way? It will work but definitely not good practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing one `cin.ingnore`

```
default:
    cout << "ERROR -- Input invalid \n";
    cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n'); // ADD this line
    bool check = again();
```

To be honest. This code is mess. Please remove recursion from it.

Comment: Are you talking about the main recursion?

Comment: You have recursion in both functions, main and again. Remove mi fix enter "5dfh" and again will be called recursively 3 times. As many as chars after number. Just use debugger and check your call stack.